# Draw real distance measures in a View

Tags: java, android, graphics

As an exercise i'm trying to implement a simple ruler app.

Is possible guess the size of a drawable in the screen exactly?
In the ecuation I'd need the resolution and the screen density (or the screen's real dimension) but since Android's API only return:

```
 DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
 DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
 DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
```

I'm wondering if is possible to do this task accurately.